# I never thought there was OR was there?

Tags: word-order

> There is so much in life to be grateful for WHICH I never thought **there was**.
>
> There is so much in life to be grateful for WHICH I never thought **was there**.

I find both to be correct. The first THERE is existential, the second one is locative. DO you agree?

Comment: No, both are ungrammatical. You need to rework this completely. Maybe something like: "There is so much in life to be grateful for — which [is something] I didn't recognize previously." (Meh, so many options.)

Answer (score 2):

Both sentences sound like somebody speaking and thinking as they speak. The first sentence needs least change; you could change "which to "and" or "but", or even leave it out and make it two sentences.

> There is so much in life to be grateful for. I never thought there was.

Here the first sentence makes it clear what the second is referring to. for more clarity you could make it

> There is so much in life to be grateful for. I never thought there was so much.

Your second sentence could be shortened for grammar-checking purposes by leaving out "in life" and "to be grateful for", giving

> There is so much which I never thought was there.

Using "which" here seems awkward to me; I would replace it with "that". However when the rest of the original sentence is put back is is no longer clear what "that" refers to. Again it might be better to split your original sentence.

> There is so much in life to be grateful for. I never thought so much was there.

Comment: So, both are correct 1) There is so much which I never thought was there. 2) There is so much which I never thought there was.

Comment: You have changed the order of sentences from your original question! As you say, _was there_ is 'locative' - it implies 'was in a particular place', while _there was_ just means 'existed'.

Answer (score -1):

I agree.  But I would rewrite it more clearly to bring out the meaning:

> There is so much in life to be grateful for, much more now than before.
> <sup>(there are MORE things I am grateful for NOW than what I'm aware of before, it's a **change in quantity**)</sup>
>
> There is so much in life to be grateful for, some which I used to take for granted.
>  <sup>(there were things I only noticed before, but now I'm grateful for them, it's a **change of perspective**)</sup>

Comment: I think that changing it to " which I now see" or "which I forgot" somewhat changes the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: @PeterJennings I hope my rewrites now don't change the meaning anymore.